# Error: Cannot find module 'eslint' when attempting to use Prettier ESLint VS Code extension in a Yarn Berry proejct with yarn linker

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarn-v2, prettier-eslint

Trying to format a file with Prettier ESLint in a worksapce that uses Yarn Berry without the nodeLinker: node-modules, the extension fails with the following error trace:

**Error stack trace:**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint'
Require stack:
- /workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js
- /ide/out/vs/loader.js
- /ide/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /ide/out/bootstrap-fork.js 
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint'
Require stack:
- /workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js
- /ide/out/vs/loader.js
- /ide/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /ide/out/bootstrap-fork.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at j4 (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:209:36)
    at zme (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:185:599)
    at vy (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:209:3779)
    at /workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:209:6494
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:1:734
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at _y (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:1:554)
    at wge (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:209:6054)
    at Object.provideDocumentRangeFormattingEdits (/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint-5.1.0-universal/dist/extension.js:210:74)
    at J.provideDocumentRangeFormattingEdits (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:101:45314)
    at /ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:101:68425
    at se.s (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:101:62837)
    at se.$provideDocumentRangeFormattingEdits (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:101:68412)
    at t.N (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:111:11199)
    at t.M (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:111:10965)
    at t.H (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:111:10007)
    at t.G (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:111:9122)
    at i.value (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:111:7952)
    at w (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:1902)
    at w.fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:2119)
    at fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:13931)
    at i.value (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:30340)
    at w (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:1902)
    at w.fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:2119)
    at fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:13931)
    at s.z (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:16976)
    at i.value (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:15428)
    at w (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:1902)
    at w.fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:2119)
    at i.acceptChunk (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:11705)
    at i.value (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:76:10992)
    at w (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:1902)
    at w.fire (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:60:2119)
    at w.u (/ide/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:19064)
```

To give more context, the extension works as expected with Yarn Berry when the `nodeLinker: node-modules` line is present in the `.yarnrc.yaml` file. But as soon as I remove that line and run `yarn install` to switch to the yarn linker, the extension stops working and throws that error.

I've already installed the vscode sdks via `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` and switched the TS version to use the workspace version, and this is how `.vscode/settings.json` looks like:

```
{
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.yarn": true,
    "**/.pnp.*": true
  },
  "eslint.nodePath": ".yarn/sdks",
  "typescript.tsdk": ".yarn/sdks/typescript/lib",
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
  "prettier.prettierPath": ".yarn/sdks/prettier/index.js"
}
```

Could this be a bug with the Prettier ESLint extension itself not using `eslint.nodePath`? Is there a workaround I can apply to make it the yarn node version instead of the global one?